# Why does a given attribute disappears after using dplyr::mutate?

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes, dplyr, tibble

I have given some attributes to my data frame.

This just saves me some typing. I work a lot with the `dplyr` package and especially with the `mutate` command.

But after using `mutate` on my data frame the attributes I have given to the data frame disappear.

Does anyone know why R or `dplyr` is doing that?

Here is a small example:

```
df <- data.frame(n = seq(1,1000),
       abc = rep(1,1000))
library(dplyr); library(data.table)
df <- df %>% setattr(., "my_attribute", "this thing is 1000 entries long") %>% 
                mutate_at(.vars = "abc", as.character)
```

... and if I list my attributes, R gives me:

```
> str(attributes(df))
List of 3
$ class    : chr "data.frame"
$ names    : chr [1:2] "n" "abc"
$ row.names: int [1:1000] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1984).

Comment: Maybe you should change the order of your dplyr verbs.

Comment: Where is `setattr` from? data.table? Without extending the dependency graph, rlang does have `set_attrs`.

Comment: I meant it in general. @alistaire yes, from data.table!

Answer (score 3):

The `mutate` function is resulting in the expected loss of attributes (even though you only coerced a single column to a different class.) So set your attribute after the mutate-operation:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_at(.vars = "abc", as.character) %>% 
                  setattr(., "my_attribute", "this thing is 1000 entries long")
#> names(attributes(df))
#[1] "class"        "names"        "row.names"    "my_attribute"
```

Comment: `setattr` doesn't seem to come with tidyverse?

Comment: @Matifou It was in pkg::data.table. I probably could have used base::attr as well, but in the subsequent 5 year I think the old dot is now supposed to be `.data`